# Incorrect syntax error sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

```
CREATE PROC CreateOrUpdate
    @ID INT,
    @NRIC VARCHAR(50),
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Description VARCHAR(50),
    @Location1 VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@ID = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblBlacklist (NRIC, Name, Description, createdatetime, Location1)
        VALUES (@NRIC, @Name, @Description, GETDATE(), @Location1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tblBlacklist
        SET NRIC = @NRIC,
            Name = @Name,
            Description = @Description,
            createdatetime = GETDATE()
        WHERE ID = @ID 
          AND Location1 = @Location1
    END
END

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ContactViewAll]    Script Date: 15- 
Apr-2017 7:39:13 AM ******/
CREATE PROC ViewAll
    @Location1 VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM tblBlacklist
    WHERE Location1 = @Location1
END
```

I cannot see any errors within my coding. The error message is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CreateOrUpdate, Line 28 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROC'

Please help me thanks.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, you were shown a box with a suggestion that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because syntax and functionality between them varies. Why did you ignore that suggestion? You've simply made it take longer for you to get an answer, because we now have to wait for you to add it so that we know how to help you.

Comment: Thats easy - Your missing a go - Oh didnt see it was old an already answered :)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to add a go between your two create statements, and remove the system comment:

```
CREATE PROC CreateOrUpdate
@ID int,
@NRIC varchar(50),
@Name varchar(50),
@Description varchar(50),
@Location1 varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
IF(@ID=0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblBlacklist(NRIC,Name,Description,createdatetime,Location1)
VALUES(@NRIC,@Name,@Description,getdate(),@Location1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE tblBlacklist
SET
    NRIC = @NRIC,
    Name = @Name,
    Description = @Description,
    createdatetime = getdate()
WHERE ID= @ID and Location1=@Location1
END
END

GO


CREATE PROC ViewAll
@Location1 varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM tblBlacklist
WHERE Location1 = @Location1
END

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

try surround your input parameters inside  fitst brace ()

Comment: Using parentheses around the list of parameters is not required.